# ChartJS not work in .php loaded by jquery .load() (AJAX)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, chart.js

this plugin not work when I am using jquery ajax function .load() How to solve this problem? This is my .php code:

```
<script src="../Chart.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../functions.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="../external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

And this is my functions.js:
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var randomScalingFactor = function(){ return Math.round(Math.random()*100)};
    var lineChartData = {
      labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
      datasets : [
        {
          label: "My First dataset",
          fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
          strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
          pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
          pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
          pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
          pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
          data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
        },
        {
          label: "My Second dataset",
          fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
          strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
          pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
          pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
          pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
          pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
          data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
        }
      ]

    }

  window.onload = function(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
      responsive: true
    });
  }
});
```

Why it is not working? This code is from sample in package of this plugin! So how it is possible it doesn't work? I think it is because of using AJAX function from jquery called .load(). How to solve this problem? Please help.

Comment: Are you using file_get_contents() or loading any external content in your PHP code?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working example of your code, i have removed the "onload" assignment, since you already have an document ready event that runs the whole thing. And moved out the function and data that doesnt need to be in there. Have a look and let me know if theres somehting you dont understand

```
 window.onload = function(){ //is removed
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L7zgL02w/2/

And also, you should load jquery.js before the other files (since your functions.js uses jquery)